# Android - How to handle swipe right or left gestures on buttons

Tags: java, android

I made a simple keyboard and what i want is when the user drags finger over the keys to the right side do something
i wrote some codes which works however when blank. it doesn't function on the keys like this image

here my main class and i used OnGestureListener and OnClickListener interfaces
I also saved x,y, but this mode works for the empty part of the page

[image: 1]

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener , GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {

    private float x1 , x2 , y1 , y2;
    private static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 150;
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    private Button button_00 , button_0 , button_1 , button_2 , button_3 , button_4 , button_5 , button_6 , button_7 , button_8 , button_9 ;
    private Button button_10 , button_11 , button_12;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(MainActivity.this , this);

        initButtons();
        

        
    }

    private void initButtons() {
        button_00 = findViewById(R.id.button_00);
        button_0 = findViewById(R.id.button_0);
        button_1 = findViewById(R.id.button_1);
        button_2 = findViewById(R.id.button_2);
        button_3 = findViewById(R.id.button_3);
        button_4 = findViewById(R.id.button_4);
        button_5 = findViewById(R.id.button_5);
        button_6 = findViewById(R.id.button_6);
        button_7 = findViewById(R.id.button_7);
        button_8 = findViewById(R.id.button_8);
        button_9 = findViewById(R.id.button_9);
        button_10 = findViewById(R.id.button_10);
        button_11 = findViewById(R.id.button_11);
        button_12 = findViewById(R.id.button_12);
        

    }
    
    
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

        switch (event.getAction()) {

            // Starting to swipe time gesture
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
                x1 = event.getX();
                y1 = event.getY();
                break;
            // Ending time swipe gesture
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
                x2 = event.getX();
                y2 = event.getY();

                // Getting value for horizontal swipe
                float valueX = x2 - x1;
                // Getting value for vertical swipe
                float valueY = y2 - y1;

                // Left and Right
                if (Math.abs((valueX)) > MIN_DISTANCE) {

                    // Detect left to right swipe
                    if (x2>x1)
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
               
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific by providing what you have achieved so far and what is the error you are facing in your current implementation? Thanks.

Comment: If there isn't any pre made solution, you could save the movement start location (x, y) and listen the movement, and if movement direction is to the right after X ms, do the functionality you want

Comment: Hi , i added my code, thanks for answer

Answer (score 0):

you can use View Pager component for this

here's a link for knowing how to create view pager:https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-swipe-view-2